# Is there an inflatable pillow that can be inflated by hand : a piston, hand pump or a rotating handle?

Tags: india, gear, sleeping

Is there an inflatable pillow, preferably ultra-light material, and inflatable by hand, not by blowing with the mouth. May be with a small hand piston or hand pump. There are these torch lights that charge by rotating a handle, somewhat like that. To be used in (Indian non-AC) trains. I am not good at blowing through little nozzles. Or the pillow I end up buying are too unfriendly to blow, require pressing the nozzle too tightly to see a tiny opening and  have to blow till eyes pop out, like a lung exercise!

Comment: Most pillows I have seen use the same kind of nozzles as small airbeds and balls. You can buy a pump for those and carry it as a separate item.

Comment: Is there a pump that is buyable separately ?

Comment: Yes, almost shops that sell airbeds, balls to be used on the beach and so on have them.

Comment: Edited the question to be more on gear than shopping.

Comment: @WhirlMind good edit, I have retracted my close vote and +1 to the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are self-inflating pillows, which work in the same manner as self-inflating sleeping mats, no blowing required, just open the valve and air is drawn into the internal foam structure. To deflate they need rolling tightly with the valve open and then close the valve to keep the pillow compressed.

The one's I've seen are quite lightweight but they are definitely bulkier than ones you have to blow into.

Comment: The self inflating one I have is useful for something to sit on, but not for something under your head to sleep, unless you fold it. Can do for a person camping, but not a replacement for a normal pillow for most.

Answer (score 5):

I have never seen pillows that have a build in pump but I have seen many pumps that can be used for pillows, inflatable balls, small airbeds and so on.
Most of them are foot operated but the smaller ones can mostly be hand operated as well.

And besides dedicated pumps, many small bike pumps can be used for pillows as well, as long as you have the right attachment or adapter.
[image: set of adapters]
Like the red one in this picture (Picture taken from a [shop catalog](https://www.hubo.be/nl/p/adapter-set-voor-pomp-voetbalnaald/53623.html).)

Shops that are likely to sell pumps:
Out-of-doors sports shops.
Camping equipment shops.
Toy shops near bodies of water, where they sell blow up balls and use on the water airbeds.
Bike shops and shops selling bikes and parts will most likely have a wide range of bike pumps, often with the needed attachment as part of the set or separate. Just a bike pump will not do, as you can not connect it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is

- google for "self-inflating pillow"
- google for "foot pump" or "inflator" etc.
- google for "bicycle pump" and "pump adapter"

Substitute your favourite search enging for google.